# Реализация Input Search. Поисковая строка

Tags: html, css

Коллеги, добрый день!

Как реализовать вот такой input search?
Смотри фото.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пишите html, пишите css и у вас получается такой вот input

Comment: Ну, как вариант - сделать `div`, в него запихнуть `img`, `input` и `button`, а дальше экспериментировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам готовая форма:

```css
.search__form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.web__search {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 0 0 120px;
  border: 2px solid #b4cfdb;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: gray;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  fill: #53a6ca;
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 4px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #53a6ca;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search__form">
  <form action="" method="GET">
    <input class="web__search" type="text" placeholder="Поиск" name="name" required-placeholder="">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Поиск">
  </form>
  <svg class="icon" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто!!! Огромное спасибо!!!!

Comment: Сделано!) Еще раз благодарю!)